# Spring.NET - Upgrade when Upgrading to NHibernate 2.0 from 1.1?

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I want to upgrade to [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) 2.0 from NHibernate 1.1.

Am I obliged to upgrade Spring.NET to v1.2 as well since we're using the NHibernate/Spring.NET integration module? We're currently publishing our releases under .NET Framework 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a few months ago and didn't have any major issues.  I think I had to make a couple of changes to a few relevant calls, and use the NHibernate20 assembly.  Give it a go, what harm is it going to do?  As long as your code is in source control you should be able to revert back. And then you can run your tests ;-)

.NET Framework 3.0 or 3.5 is okay as well, as they both sit on top of .net 2.0: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DotNet.svg

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded spring as well - a couple of small modifications were needed (to hibernate codeand to spring transaction configuration)